# how to submit form and cc to an email filled in the field

Tags: javascript, forms, email

I am writing a html form which will address to "project@abc.com" and want to cc this form to the "budget_email".

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="../script/common.js"></SCRIPT>
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2800.1595" name=GENERATOR>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input name="recipient" value="project@abc.com">
    <input name="Budget Email" type="text" id="budget_email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">    
</form>
```

Comment: `I want to cc this form to the "budget_email"` Didn't understand what are you trying to do exactly.

Comment: I want the form to be sent to "project@abc.com" and to the email account input in the field "budget_email".  Thanks.

Comment: I've still not understood what exactly are you trying to achieve. But are you referring to the [`mailto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links) link?

Comment: I'm not sure if mailto works but what I need is that the form will be sent to two email addresses simultaneously when I press the submit button and one of the email address is filled by user in the input field.

Comment: Do you want to open user's email client or send email without opening mail client?

Comment: This code sends information to some server, who sends the email. So, we need to see the server code. As the form action is empty, the server script address should be into `../script/common.js`. Show it.

Answer (score 0):

To send an email with the data of the form to two email addresses, you need to catch your form submit server side by using for example `PHP`, and then process the data and send an email using either the build in `mail()` function (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)) or using a library like `PHPmailer` ([here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer))

To set a `CC` using the `mail()` function, you need to add

```
$headers .= 'CC: email@domein.com' . "\r\n";
```

To the headers argument of `mail()`.

An example full code would be:

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['recipient'];
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello SO!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: ".$_POST['Budget Email']."\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```